# angular directive manipulating ngRepeat items with global switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

So, I have the following image in my mind:

A new directive `compactList` is applicable to the element containing the `ngRepeat` directive which does the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="for item in items" compact-list limit-to="3">{{item}}</li>
```

What the directive does:

- the given limit (in the above example: 3) should limit the displayed entries to a maximum of 3 items
- on hovering over (mouseover) any of the visible items, the rest of the list will be displayed, too (expanded)
- on mouseout, the additional items will be hidden again - 3 items remain visible

So, the whole point from a user's perspective is to have a read-only list which can be quite long. In order not to clutter my layout, I would love to limit the list to a couple of entries. Only while the user hovers over the compacted list, it is expanded. Gee what a nice feature!

From a technical perspective, that's my basic concept:

1. directive `compactList` has a `priority > 1000`, thus executed before `ng-repeat`. It manipulates the list item template by adding CSS classes depending on the `$index` as well as adding mouseover and mouseout events
2. when `ng-repeat` executes, the manipulated list template will add a "hide item" CSS class for each template instance with `$index < limitTo`
3. there must be a global switch (`collapsed=false/true`)
4. on mouseover, the directive-global switch `collapsed` is set to false, by means of e.g. `ngClass` the hidden items will be shown. That means, the list is "expanded"
5. on mouseout, the directive-global switch `collapsed` is set to true again. Through the `ngClass` trick, the items 4...n will be hidden again

I sort of managed to get thing done with manipulating the template. But I fail at coming up with a decent solution for a "directive-global switch". What Angular mechanisms can I use to attach such a variable to the `compactList` directive, with only one instance valid for all `ng-repeat` items? However, it must not be "really" global because there may be multiple compactList directives on the same page. So, only global to the "scope" of the directive. I wrote scope in parentheses because `ngRepeat` creates *multiple scopes* so I am not sure where the "parent scope" actually is.

Since `ngRepeat` is operating on the `<li>` items which are multiplied and not on the `<ul>` tag, it seems to me that placing the directive `compactList` on the same level as ngRepeat may be one level too deep. Maybe the parent element must be equipped with such a variable? But this sound not very elegant.

Does somebody have ideas how to solve this? Note: I am definitely not looking for some hackish solution. I would like to have an idea how to do this in an elegant, Angular-conform way. I expect people looking at my code  to go WOW instead of ARGH ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a pretty sweet solution in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAfdB09DGUcYTWvQ7Bnj?p=preview) :

Here is an exemple with two "list" items.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
  <div ng-mouseleave="list.expand = false" ng-mouseover="list.expand = true" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div ng-if="$first">
      List n° {{listIndex}}
    </div> 
    <div ng-show="$index < 3 || list.expand">
      {{item.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I work with `ng-mouseleave` and `ng-mouseover` that set the dynamic property `list.exand` to `true` or `false`.

The value part are displaying depending on the limit you want (could be defined in a var in the scope) and if the list should expand or not.

```
ng-show="$index < 3 || list.expand"
```

Tell me if you think that could meet your needs. Anyway you'll need to adapt it a bit to how your directive works.

If you want to help me integrate this, share your directive code (even better if you put an exemple in a plunker) and i'll do my best.

Hope it helped

### EDIT :

I passed some time to implements this directive, and here it is.

See the uses in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKpWUl85bw8u1DGwhcpC?p=preview)

I came up with two directives that should be use like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="(listIndex,list) in lists">
   <div compact-list>
     <div ng-click="getClExpand()" ng-repeat="item in list">
      <div ng-if="$first">
        List n° {{listIndex}}
      </div> 
      <div limit-to="2">
        {{item.value}}
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The `compact-list` directive add the `ng-mouseenter`, `ng-mouseleave` directives.

The `limit-to` add the `ng-show` according to the number you gave.

**`compact-list` directive**

```
app.directive('compactList', function ($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller:function($scope){
        $scope.clExpand = false;
      },
      replace: false,
      link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
        //don't forget to remove the directive before the compile to avoid infinite digests.
        element.removeAttr("compact-list");
        element.attr("ng-mouseenter","clExpand = true");
        element.attr("ng-mouseleave","clExpand = false");
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }; 
  });
```

**`limit-to` directive :**

```
app.directive('limitTo', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false,
      //You can't use limit-to withouth compact-list
      require:"^^compactList",
      link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
        element.attr("ng-show","$index < "+attrs.limitTo+" || clExpand");
        //don't forget to remove the directive before the compile to avoid infinite digests.
        element.removeAttr("limit-to");
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };  
});
```

The plus : You can choose what part of your item you want to hide by placing the limit-to directive wherever you want. (If you want to hide the description for the items, put it on the description div, if you want to hid the whole item, put it on the whole item div.)

Hope it helped.

### EDIT:

(by andimeier)

Add `scope=true` property to the `compact-list` directive and it is still better (see my comments below). So, the `compact-list` would be:

**`compact-list` directive**

```
app.directive('compactList', function ($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      controller:function($scope){
        $scope.clExpand = false;
      },
      replace: false,
      link: function link(scope,element, attrs) {
        //don't forget to remove the directive before the compile to avoid infinite digests.
        element.removeAttr("compact-list");
        element.attr("ng-mouseenter","clExpand = true");
        element.attr("ng-mouseleave","clExpand = false");
        $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    }; 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome demonstration, Okazari. However, if I rearrange the 2 lists to be one after the other (instead of being nested), the mouseover over _one_ expands _both_ lists - see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3PPCsSyPyJs3VfJxcKqf?p=preview). I think in terms of decoupling, the solution is not ideal - although it gave me some very valuable tipps! Besides, I am very interested if there is a solution without having to introduce an element "above" the ngRepeat (as you did) to hold the "expand flag" for the ngRepeat items. Not sure if this is possible at all ...

Comment: @andimeier Right, i totaly derped on the isolated scopes. And now it's too far in my memory and i don't remember why i did it this way. Anyway in my humble opinion for this kind of "simple" behavior, i'd definitly do it like in my first exemple without any custom directive. This is much more flexible and understandable and still do the same job.

Comment: I agree it's certainly possible without resorting to directives. However, I am very interested if this would be possible with directives as well - because simply adding a directive "compact-list=5" to any ng-repeat'ed element would the simpliest and most beautiful use case IMHO, from a user's point of view. So the goal is to come up with something possibly complicated, but for the _user_ of the directive, it should be a piece of cake. And I feel I would gain a lot of further insight into directives when solving this in this manner (also a goal).

Comment: in order to make your solution work with 2 independent lists (not being in the same ngRepeat construct), you just have to set `scope=true` for the compact-list directive. Then it works, see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Rxm6wXW60lGCqyZRJPm?p=preview). Having added this, I checkmark your answer, thanks for your help!